# list of publications, grouped and ordered

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, classicthesis, thesis, multibib

In my thesis (based on the `classicthesis` package) I'd like to create a page with a list of my own publications. I want to be able to group them under different headings ("Conference Publications", "Journal Publications" etc.), and give them a specific order.

I've tried the `multibib` package, but I don't just want a second bibliography. I need the possibility to group and order entries by hand.

I'm using BibTeX and `natbib` for bibliography management. For consistency, I'd like to rely on BibTeX entries for creating the list of publications, but there might be a simpler solution without BibTeX.

Comment: You could do this relatively easily, I think, with Biblatex, if that's an option.

Comment: @cfr I don't know, how would that look like?

Comment: It means using Biblatex and, probably, Biber, rather than **natbib**, **multibib** and BibTeX etc. Biblatex offers a lot more flexibility. In particular, you can filter entries when printing bibliographies according to entry type, keyword, category etc. etc. It handles multiple bibliographies much more smoothly than traditional BibTeX.

Comment: Note that the newest classic thesis template (v4.2) has switched to using biblatex to manage bibliographies, and has a simple example of what you're looking for. Download the template and test if it works for you https://bitbucket.org/amiede/classicthesis/downloads

Comment: @PhilipPirrip When I compile the new classicthesis template in the usual way with TeXShop, there's a "Publications" section now, but it doesn't show any bibliography entries.

Comment: @clstaudt You have to make sure the right processor is run too - it's either biber or bibtex8. Check the classicthesis-config.tex file and change the biblatex processor. It's bibtex8 be default;  biber is much better but doesn't work for everyone. Then pdflatex ClassicThesis; bibtex8 ClassicThesis1-blx; bibtex8 ClassicThesis; pdflatex ClassicThesis. (with biber, it's pdflatex ClassicThesis, biber ClassicThesis; pdflatex Classicthesis).

Comment: @PhilipPirrip It worked after changing "bibtex" to "biber". bibtex, biblatex, bibtex8, biber, natbib... this gets seriously confusing.

Comment: @clstaudt I guess that's what happens with software stuck in 1980's. Confusing it is.

Comment: Is there any news here?

Comment: @Johannes_B  yes, I got pragmatic and formatted the publications page by hand using sections and `itemize`. ;)

Answer (score 3):

This solved my problem and saved me time otherwise spent on studying bibtex, biber, biblatex, bibtex8 and natbib.

```
\chapter*{Publications} % Publications page text

\section*{In This Thesis}

Some of the research leading to this thesis has appeared previously in the following publications.

\subsection*{Journal Articles}

\begin{itemize}
\item Author A, Author B, Author C:
\textbf{Paper Title}.
-- \textit{A Journal}, August 2015, Paris, France
\end{itemize}

\subsection*{Conference Papers}

\begin{itemize}
\item Author A, Author B, Author C:
\textbf{Another Title}.
-- \textit{A Conference}, August 2015, Paris, France
\end{itemize}
```